# Find the infimum of $J(\phi) = \int_{\phi}^{} e^x dl$

Tags: calculus-of-variations, geodesic, euler-lagrange-equation, variational-analysis

Dear members of community! I have a trouble, with my attempts to understand provided in solution manual for such task.

**Task:**

So let the standard Cartesian coordinate system $(x,y)$ be given on the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let's assume that $$dl \overset{\operatorname{def}}{=} \sqrt{(dx)^2 + (dy)^2}.$$

Let $\Omega$ the set of $C^{(1)}$ smooth paths on plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ with initial point $O(0;0)$ and ending at a point $A(2;4)$.

Consider a functional $J: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
J(\phi) = \int_{\phi}^{} e^x dl, \quad \forall \phi \in \Omega.
$$
Find the $\underset{\phi \in \Omega} \inf J(\phi)$.

***Provided solution:*** (manual solution)

The Euler-Lagrange equation for this functional is given by:
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi'(t)} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi(t)} = 0,
$$
where $L(\phi(t),\phi'(t)) = e^{\phi(t)} \sqrt{\phi'(t)^2 + 1}$

Solving the Euler-Lagrange equation subject to the boundary conditions $\phi(0) = 0$ and $\phi(1) = 2$ will give us the path $\phi(t) = 2t$ that minimizes the functional $J(\phi)$.

After we get:
$$
\underset{\phi \in \Omega} \inf J(\phi) = \int_{0}^{1} e^{2t} \sqrt{2^2 + 1} dt = e^2 \sqrt{5}.
$$

*My trouble:*

And to be honest, I did not quite understand how the Euler-Lagrange equations are essentially solved in this case, i.e. the minimality of this functional is proved, and why the Lagrangian is written in this case in this way $L(\phi(t),\phi'(t)) = e^{\phi(t)} \sqrt{\phi'(t)^2 + 1}$. Is it possible to explain in more detail how the minimality of the functional is proved in this case, because the lower bound is then found?

**UPD:**

Having returned to this problem 5 times already, I still understand that this solution is more than strange and not entirely correct. Therefore, after reading one more book on the calculus of variations, I came to the conclusion that we should try again to do the same steps using the parametrization of the curve.

***My attempt solution:***

First, I need to express $J(\phi)$ in terms of the parameterization of $\phi$. Let $\phi(t) = (x(t),y(t))$ be a parameterization of a path $\phi$ with $t \in [0,1]$ such that $\phi(0) = O$ and $\phi(1) = A$. Then, we have
\begin{align*}
J(\phi) &= \int_{\phi} e^x dl \
= \int_0^1 e^{x(t)} \sqrt{(dx/dt)^2 + (dy/dt)^2} dt \
= \int_0^1 e^{x(t)} \sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2} dt.
\end{align*}

Next, we write the Euler-Lagrange equation for $J(\phi)$. The Euler-Lagrange equation for a functional of the form $J(\phi) = \int_a^b L(\phi,\phi',t) dt$ is
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi'} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi} &= 0,
\end{align*}
where $L(\phi,\phi',t)$ is the Lagrangian, and $\phi'$ denotes the derivative of $\phi$ with respect to $t$.

For our functional $J(\phi)$, we have $L(\phi,\phi',t) = e^{x(t)} \sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2}$, and so the Euler-Lagrange equation becomes
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi'} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi} &= 0 \
\frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{e^{x(t)} x'(t)}{\sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2}} \right) - e^{x(t)} \frac{y'(t)^2}{\sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2}^3} = 0.
\end{align*}

After simplify this equation by multiplying both sides by $\sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2}^3$ and using the chain rule to get
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt} \left( e^{x(t)} x'(t) \sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2}^2 \right) - e^{x(t)} x'(t)^2 - e^{x(t)} y'(t)^2 &= 0 \\
\frac{d}{dt} \left( e^{x(t)} x'(t) \sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2}^2 \right) &= e^{x(t)} \left( x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2 \right).
\end{align*}
(use Maple with subs for evaluate and check correct equation)

Integrate both sides of the equation with respect to $t$ from $0$ to $1$ and use the boundary conditions $\phi(0) = O$ and $\phi(1) = A$ to obtain
\begin{align*}
&\left. e^{x(t)} x'(t) \sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2}^2 \right|_{0}^1 = \int_0^1 e^{x(t)} \left( x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2 \right) dt \\
\Rightarrow \quad & e^{1} 2^2 - e^{0} 0^2 = \int_0^1 e^{x(t)} \left( x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2 \right) dt \\
\Rightarrow \quad & 4e = \int_0^1 e^{x(t)} \left( x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2 \right) dt.
\end{align*}

We see that the integral on the right-hand side of the equation is the same as $J(\phi)$, up to a constant factor. Therefore, to find the infimum of $J(\phi)$ over all $\phi \in \Omega$, it suffices to find the infimum of the integral $\int_0^1 e^{x(t)} \left( x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2 \right) dt$ over all $C^{(1)}$ smooth paths $\phi$ with initial point $O$ and ending point $A$.

Note that the integrand $e^{x(t)} \left( x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2 \right)$ is non-negative, and so the infimum is achieved when the integrand is zero, that is, when $x'(t) = y'(t) = 0$ for all $t$. In other words, the infimum is achieved when the path $\phi$ is constant and equal to the point $(2,4)$. Therefore, the infimum of $J(\phi)$ over all $\phi \in \Omega$ is
\begin{align*}
\inf_{\phi \in \Omega} J(\phi) &= \inf_{\phi \in \Omega} \int_{\phi} e^x dl \ = \inf_{\phi \in \Omega} \int_0^1 e^{x(t)} \sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2} dt = \inf_{\phi \in \Omega} \int_0^1 e^{x(t)} \cdot 0 dt = 0,
\end{align*}
where the infimum is taken over all $C^{(1)}$ smooth paths $\phi$ with initial point $O$ and ending point $A$.

$0$ and the previously received answer differ very much, in the end, if you follow the rules for searching for functionals, then you still get $0$? Right? Or am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: A little confused by the solution provided because the path $\phi(t) = 2t$ is not in the set $\Omega$ of $C^1$ paths from (0,0) to (2,4). It may refer to only the x component of the solution.

Comment: @iglizworks

in fact, yes, because I'm a little surprised that, in principle, such a record, because there is still a component $y$ in any case, I still do not quite understand why such a solution to the problem ...

Comment: Is the solution manual online or published somewhere?

Comment: @Qmechanic
in fact, this is a task from one public, and there was an indication in such a form that the answer is just that, in fact. Someone said that in fact this functionality has no lower bound, trying to solve ... i.e. is not solution manual in classic meaning

Comment: $\uparrow$ Link?

Comment: @Qmechanic

the original task is translated, respectively, the original is in another language, the hint was given by the participants in the form of an image, I just translated and rewrote it here ... the fact is that this topic, the task is essentially an invention of the author, a foreign public ... I understand which is clearly the wrong solution, some say the answer should be $e^2 + 1$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. OP's functional is
   $$ J[x,y] ~:=~\int_{(0,0)}^{(2,4)}\!\mathrm{d}t~L, \qquad
   L~=~e^x\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2},\tag{A}$$
   where dot means differentiation wrt. $t$.
2. $J$ is the arclength for the metric tensor
   $$\mathrm{d}s^2~=~e^{2x}\left(\mathrm{d}x^2+ \mathrm{d}y^2\right),
   \tag{B}$$
   which in physics is known as a [Liouville wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_field_theory). Intuitively, it is more and more expensive in terms of arclength to move further and further into the positive $x$-plane. So the problem is to determine the [geodesics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic).
3. Note that the functional $J$ is worldline reparametrization invariant. Assuming the solution $t\mapsto y(t)$ is injective, we may assume an
   analogue of the [*static gauge*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_fixing)
   $$y(t)~=~t.\tag{C}$$
4. Then  OP's functional becomes
   $$ J[x] ~:=~\int_0^4\mathrm{d}t~L, \qquad
   L~=~e^x\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+1},\tag{D}$$
   with Dirichlet boundary conditions (DBC)
   $$ x(0)~=~0, \qquad x(4)~=~2.\tag{E}$$
5. Since $t$ does not appear explicitly in the Lagrangian $L$, we know
   from [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem)
   that the energy
   $$ -e^{x_0}~:=~E~:=~\dot{x}\frac{\partial
   L}{\partial\dot{x}}-L~=~-\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+1}}\tag{F}$$
   is a negative constant.
6. This leads to a 1st order ODE:
   $$ \dot{x}~=~\pm\sqrt{e^{2(x-x_0)}-1},\qquad x~\geq~x_0.\tag{G}$$
   Keeping in mind the static gauge (C), the solutions are of the form
   $$ \pm(y-y_0)~=~\arctan\sqrt{e^{2(x-x_0)}-1},\tag{H}$$
   or
   $$ \cos^{-2}(y-y_0)~=~\tan^2(y-y_0)+1~=~e^{2(x-x_0)},\tag{I}$$
   so that the geodesics are of the form
   $$ x(t)-x_0~=~-\ln|\cos(y-y_0)|,\tag{J}$$
   see e.g. Fig. 1.

[image: img]

$\uparrow$ Fig. 1. A typical geodesic in the $xy$ plane.

7. We conclude from eq. (J) that the $y$-interval length for a geodesic must be less than $\pi$. But the DBC calls for length=$4$. So OP's endpoints $O$ and $A$ are not connected via a geodesic.
8. By continuity a minimal curve $O\to A$ must pass through a point $C(x_1,2)$ for some $x_1\in[-\infty,\infty[$. Assume that $x_1>-\infty$ is finite. Then the 2 curves $O\to C$ and $C\to A$ have $y$-interval length$=2$ [which is less than $\pi$ so that they are geodesics] but it is more than $\pi/2$. We conclude from eq. (J) that $\dot{x}=0$ at some internal points, say $D$ and $B$ on each of the 2 geodesic branches $O\to C$ and $C\to A$, i.e. the $x$-coordinates at $B$ and $D$ are smaller than at $C$. We can lower the arclength by straightning the curve $D\to B$ [and in this way move further away from the Liouville wall] i.e. lowering $x_1$. We leave it to the reader to turn this handwaving argument into a proof that $x_1=-\infty$.
9. This suggests that a minimal curve would consist of piecewise straight lines
   $$ (0,0) \to (-\infty,0) \to (-\infty,4) \to (2,4), \tag{K}$$
   corresponding to the arclength
   $$ J[x,y]~=~\int_{-\infty}^0\mathrm{d}x~e^x + 0 +\int_{-\infty}^2\mathrm{d}x~e^x~=~1+e^2. \tag{L}$$

Comment: A very interesting solution, in the direction of physical interpretation. True, I did not quite understand the transition eq. $J$ from to the point 7.

Comment: I updated the answer.